# Excel app default is XML Handler - why?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

Why is XML Handler my default app for XLS files?  Brand new laptop, all previous versions were simple .XLS files.

Comment: Why? Who knows? 'Why?' is never a good question for SE, because the only person who can correctly answer is the manufacturer of that particular machine.